# Usage Examples of DateJS in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, datejs

I have installed DateJS in my NodeJS project for easy handling of adding months. I added it in my package.json.

```
 "datejs": "*"
```

Then installed it via :

```
root@v-hj-0190:~/deepak/appJade# npm -d install
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@1.4.28
npm info using node@v0.10.33
npm info preinstall appJade@0.0.0
npm info trying registry request attempt 1 at 15:08:34
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/datejs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/datejs
npm info install datejs@1.0.0-rc3 into /root/deepak/appJade
npm info installOne datejs@1.0.0-rc3
npm info preinstall datejs@1.0.0-rc3
npm info build /root/deepak/appJade/node_modules/datejs
npm info linkStuff datejs@1.0.0-rc3
npm info install datejs@1.0.0-rc3
npm info postinstall datejs@1.0.0-rc3
npm info build /root/deepak/appJade
npm info linkStuff appJade@0.0.0
npm info install appJade@0.0.0
npm info postinstall appJade@0.0.0
npm info prepublish appJade@0.0.0
datejs@1.0.0-rc3 node_modules/datejs
npm info ok
root@v-hj-0190:~/deepak/appJade#
```

I have added the require line in app.js

```
...
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Date = require('datejs');
...
```

But the following codes are still giving error:

```
var approvalDate =  Date.today();
                                 ^
TypeError: Object function Date() { [native code] } has no method 'today'
..


var n = 6;
console.log(n.months().fromNow());
                      ^
TypeError: Object 6 has no method 'months'
```

Note: I am new to NodeJS and need examples of how to integrate/use DateJS in a project.Only direct functions have been provided everywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

datejs works by extending the javascript built in Date, so no need to assign the require to a variable. Instead of..

```
var Date = require('datejs');
```

just do the require:

```
require('datejs')
```

and then when you will be all set (alternatively, if you have some reason to assign the module to a variable, use something other than 'Date').

Comment: thanks mike that worked..Just had a doubt will this extended date object work with mongoose n mongodb querying